# Large data from SQLite on ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, listadapter, android-cursor

If CursorAdapter is deprecated, what's the recommended way to manage large data in a ListView?

After API level 11 there's LoaderManager. But [apparently](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/#how_to_deal_with_cursoradapters) you need to use it together with CursorAdapter?

Is there a newer way?

Comment: Where do you see `CursorAdapter` being deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CursorAdapter` is not deprecated. The constructor `CursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c)` is. You just need to use the other constructor `CursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags)`.

Comment: Oh, so I basically always need to pass FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER (the one flag left). I didn't read the javadoc on the flags before and was confused about only the "base constructor" (the one without optional parameters) being deprecated. It makes sense now that you said, even though it's kinda ugly. :/

Comment: My guess is they will add more flags in the future.